# MySQL throws error even though query syntax is correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This has got be stumped. I've almost literally copied this query directly into heidiSQL's query field and run it successfully.

I'm getting this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO dots(`name`, `sambandsnr`, `dslam`, `ip`, `lat`, `lng`, `on' at line 1
> ```

On this query

```
DELETE FROM dots;

INSERT INTO dots(`name`, `sambandsnr`, `dslam`, `ip`, `lat`, `lng`, `online`)
VALUES
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "..."),
    ("...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...", "...");
```

The real script has real data and around 800 rows. Seriously, I have copy&pasted the first 10 rows and run the query manually successfully. That completely stumps me as to how there can be an error at line 1.

Any help would be appreciated

---

Edit: I just copied the ENTIRE failing script into the query editor and ran it. It ran successfully. !?!?!?

Comment: I often get this when I'm using a reserved word. But it seems your not. Have you tried scaling down and see when it breaks? Try adding a single row without some of the columns and see if it works. Then add columns incrementally to see when it breaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to send two queries at once.

Either send them separately, or use a multi-query function to do that ([`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) in `PHP`).

To do this you have to use `MySQLi` extension: `MySQL` extension is not able to send multiple queries in one statement.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> `mysql_query()` sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Comment: I'm using mysqli::query. Is there an object oriented way of using your function? EDIT: mysqli::multi_query works, thanks

Comment: @Codemonkey: sure, `mysqli::multi_query`